# How can I get only one object property data from mongodb collection by using nodejs?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

From mongodb collection I want to get only one property like if I had a array of object structure

```
[
  {
     _id: 'property1',
     name: 'property1',
     value: 1
  },
  {
    _id: 'property2',
    name: 'property2',
    value: 2
  }
]
```

So here I don't want to get whole collection, instead I only just need name from all the documents in the collection

Comment: Use [`find` with projection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)